# Opening several javascript link from page

Tags: php, goutte

I am using `"fabpot/goutte": "^3.2"` and use `PHP 7.3.5`.

I am trying to access the following page and click the link - `https://www.forexfactory.com/calendar.php?month=nov.2019` - to open the below box:

[image]

I tried to filter all this links, however `no links are found`:

```
$subCrawler->filter('td.calendar__cell.calendar__detail.detail > a')->each(function ($node) {
    $link = $node->link();
    print $link ."\n";
    print $node->text() ."\n";
});
```

Any suggestions how to click the link with goutte and get the source text and usual effect text?

Comment: PHP5.3 is now very very old and insecure. Can you upgrade

Comment: @RiggsFolly Yes, I can!

Comment: I am not sure the filter supports chained class names. Have you tried with `filter('td.calendar__detail > a')` or `filter('a.calendar_detail')` ?

Comment: @FerdyPruis That won't work because those links don't exist in the DOM. When you click on the event details(the folder icon), it does a `GET` request and appends to the DOM.

Answer (score 3):

Using Goutte:

```
<?php
require 'vendor/autoload.php';
use Goutte\Client;
use Symfony\Component\DomCrawler\Crawler;


$x = 1;
$LIMIT = 20; 

$client = new Client();
$crawler = $client->request('GET', 'https://www.forexfactory.com/calendar.php?month=nov.2019');
$resArray = array();
$TEMP = array();


$crawler->filter('.calendar_row')->each(function ($node) {
    global $x;
    global $LIMIT;
    global $resArray;
    global $TEMP;
    $x++;


    $EVENTID   = $node->attr('data-eventid');


    $API_RESPONSE = file_get_contents('https://www.forexfactory.com/flex.php?do=ajax&contentType=Content&flex=calendar_mainCal&details='.$EVENTID);

    $API_RESPONSE = str_replace("<![CDATA[","",$API_RESPONSE);
    $API_RESPONSE = str_replace("]]>","",$API_RESPONSE);

$html = <<<HTML
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
       $API_RESPONSE
    </body>
</html>
HTML;

 $subcrawler = new Crawler($html);

 $subcrawler->filter('.calendarspecs__spec')->each(function ($LEFT_TD) {
     global $resArray;
     global $TEMP;
     $LEFT_TD_INNER_TEXT = trim($LEFT_TD->text());

     if($LEFT_TD_INNER_TEXT == "Source"){

            $TEMP = array(); 
            $LEFT_TD->nextAll()->filter('a')->each(function ($LINK) {
                global $TEMP;   
                array_push($TEMP,$LINK->text(),$LINK->attr('href'));
            });

            $EVENT['sourceTEXT'] = $TEMP[0];
            $EVENT['sourceURL']  = $TEMP[1];
            $EVENT['latestURL']  = $TEMP[3];

            array_push($resArray,$EVENT);
    }

});   

  if($x>$LIMIT){
        echo "<pre>"; var_dump($resArray); echo "</pre>";
        exit;
   }

});
```

Using [Simple HTML DOM](https://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.io/manual.htm). You can get it from [here](https://sourceforge.net/projects/simplehtmldom/).

```
<?php
include('simple_html_dom.php');
$html = file_get_html('https://www.forexfactory.com/calendar.php?month=nov.2019');

$x = 1;
$LIMIT = 10;

foreach($html->find('.calendar_row') as $e){
    $x++;
    $EVENTID = $e->attr['data-eventid'];
    $EVENTNAME = $e->find('.event')[0]->find('div')[0]->innertext;
    echo "<h4>".$EVENTNAME."</h4><br>";

    $API_RESPONSE = file_get_html('https://www.forexfactory.com/flex.php?do=ajax&contentType=Content&flex=calendar_mainCal&details='.$EVENTID);

    $API_RESPONSE = str_replace("<![CDATA[","",$API_RESPONSE);
    $API_RESPONSE = str_replace("]]>","",$API_RESPONSE);
    $API_RESPONSE = str_get_html($API_RESPONSE);
    foreach($API_RESPONSE->find('.calendarspecs__spec') as $LEFT_TD){

        $LEFT_TD_INNER_TEXT = trim($LEFT_TD->innertext);
        if($LEFT_TD_INNER_TEXT == "Source" || $LEFT_TD_INNER_TEXT == "Usual Effect"){
            echo $LEFT_TD_INNER_TEXT.": ".$LEFT_TD->next_sibling()->innertext."<br>";
        }
    }

    if($x>$LIMIT)
        break;
    echo "<hr>";

}
```

Screenshot(Goutte): [image]

Screenshot(SIMPLE HTML DOM): [image: Is this something you want?]

Comment: Thx! Please use goutte as my other implementation is already in this library. Furthermore, my question is also about goutte. Can you recode the example?

Comment: I can try to do it. :)

Comment: @Anna.Klee Done!

Comment: Don't use "Simple HTML DOM" it's very outdated and much better alternatives exist like PHP's built-in DOM library.

Comment: Thx! One further questions: How did you get this url `file_get_contents('https://www.forexfactory.com/flex.php?do=ajax&contentType=Content&flex=calendar_mainCal&details='.$EVENTID)` Where can I find it in chrome developer console?

Comment: One final questions: How to get the links out of the `$LEFT_TD` variable? I tried to parse it using goutte itself, but nothing works for the `nextAll()` method.

Comment: @Anna.Klee You can get URL by monitoring the network tab in the developer console. When you click on those folder icons, it does a GET request to that link(dynamic Event ID).

Comment: @Anna.Klee I updated the code for getting all the links.

Comment: Sorry, to be unclear, but I meant adding `$sourceURL`, `$relatedURL`, `$source`(the Text) and `$related` to an array like `array_push($resArray, [$sourceURL, $source, $relatedURL, $related])`.

Comment: @Anna.Klee Sorry but I am confused as to what `$related` and `$relatedURL` are supposed to be?  Source specs seem to contain two URLs. Is it the second URL of the 'Source'?

Comment: `source` is `Statistics Bureau` the `sourceUrl` is `http://www.stat.go.jp/english/index.htm` and the `latestReleaseUrl` is `http://www.stat.go.jp/english/data/roudou/results/month/index.html` for example for `https://www.forexfactory.com/calendar.php?month=nov.2019#detail=107072`

Comment: @Anna.Klee Updated code and added a new screenshot, is that how you wanted it?